# Disable all controls that are connected with a form in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

Currently I use a listbox for selecting the record that a form provide to edit. What if there is no record selected in the listbox? How can I disable and empty all controls, that are connected to the forms datasource?

Comment: Please show your existing code to select the record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unbind the form from the table and use coding to place values into the unbound forms controls. There are a few things to setup prior to programming.

1. Ensure all form control names match the table field names.
2. Ensure the record source in the form properties is blank.
3. Use a loop to "plug-in" the value from a query upon list box selection.

This takes a ton more programming because you have to add in an update query on every controls update. But i have found this to be the best option since it helps prevent corrupted records since it is not bound to the record upon viewing.

When the form opens, everything should be blank, including the list box. On the list box After Update event, place in your coding to query the data set and place values in the forms controls.

I do not have the name of your table fields nor the name of your form, so i will use random names.

Coding example:

```
Private sub Listbox1_AfterUpdate()
dim rst as dao.recordset
dim strSQL as string
dim ctr as control

for each ctr in me.controls
    'Identifies if the control is a text box or combo box before trying to enter value in the incorrect control type
    if ctr.controltype = actextbox or ctr.controltype = accombobox
        strsql = "SELECT " & ctr.name & " as [FieldName] " & _
                 "FROM Table1 " & _
                 "WHERE (((Field1) ='" & me.listbox1 & "'));"
        set rst = currentdb.openrecordset(strsql)
        ctr.value = rst![FieldName]
        rst.close
        set rst = nothing
     end if
next ctr

EndCode:
If not rst is nothing then
    rst.close
    set rst = nothing
end if
end sub
```

If this doesn't work for you, let me know and we can figure out another solution.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I can't test the solution today. Will do it later.

Comment: This will not store your edits. Don't use `CurrentDb` inside a loop (use `With CurrentDb` outside the loop). Would be easier to fetch all fields in rst, then check if they match `Me.Controls`

Comment: correct, this will not store your edits to the record, but this will grab the records information and place into the corresponding control on the form. When he selects the blank in the list box, coding can be added to make all controls values = null

there are 2 ways after this type of form usage to update the records information on the table. Build a "Save Edits" button, or place an update query in each "AfterUpdate" event on every control. Save button might be easier. since the list box is determining the record to view on the form, I'm assuming the list box is connected to the primary key

Comment: Using CurrentDB inside the loop isn't a problem... the query string is only going to query the record based on the listbox and pull only the field that matches the name of the control on the form. Thus giving you only 1 record and 1 field with 1 value.

Comment: Seems you're not aware that `CurrentDb` creates a **copy** of the database object, what is slow, can lead to an error if used > 100000 times in loop (sth like object not referenced or closed).or try it with `TableDefs` and a call to it later. So better use `With` or  a  variable

Comment: good thing you cant have 100000 table fields then. Either way... there is more than one way to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072564/9439330), you use the `AfterUpdate` -Event from Gustav and you want to disable all but the ListBox.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load() ' same as ListBox_AfterUpdate, let you start with a new empty record assumin ID > 0
' Set filter.
Me.Filter = "[ID] = " & Nz(Me!NameOfYourListBox.value, 0) & ""
' Activate filter.
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim ctl As Variant
Me.AllowAdditions = Me.NewRecord 'only allo new records at start
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    On Error Resume Next ' ignore errors because control has no enabled proptery
    If ctl.Name <> "NameOfYourListBox" Then
        ctl.Enabled = Not Me.NewRecord
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 438 And Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Error other than 438 should be handled
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 'turn on errors again, if you use an error handler Goto ErrorHandlerName
Next
If Me.NewRecord Then
    Me!ID.ControlSource = ""  'hide the {New} default text on new record
Else
    Me!ID.ControlSource = "ID"
End If
End Sub
```

But if it is not necessary to start with an empty form, I would suggest using a subform (same recordsource as the form) for the edits, that gets synced without any code to the record selecting form.