# Why does Ms Access show the first record for a short time before switching to the right one?

Tags: ms-access

To reproduce do this steps. You only need the visual designer.

1. create a simple table: (ID,txt)
2. insert some records for testing
3. create a form and use the table as datasource
4. insert controls for ID, txt
5. insert a listbox and choose option 3: The form must display the record that is choosen in the listbox

Now select a record other than the first one. You have to watch carefully. The form displays the tables first record for a very short time, before the choosen record is displayed.

1. Why?
2. How can I stop this?

Hint: For better see this effect, use a large txt control with "XXXXXXXXXXX" set in the first record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have created a macro. Don't, use code in the *AfterUpdate* event of the listbox:

```
' Set filter.
Me.Filter = "[ID] = " & Nz(Me!NameOfYourListBox.Value, 0) & ""
' Activate filter.
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: I have used the assistent and, yes, a marco was created. Your solution works fine. Thank you.

Comment: If I navigated the listbox with cursorkeys, everything is ok. But when I use the mouse, in the listbox all entries disappear for short - even when I choose the already selected value.

Comment: That I cannot replicate. The explanation is, that something else interferes. Try to rebuild the form, adding the listbox as the first task.

Comment: @doev can confirm same behavior on `Ms Access 2007`with listbox unbound, if bound no flicker on after update. If you put a `Msgbox` in `Listbox_AfterUpdate()` unbound it stays empty till confirmed..

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: If so, this is an Access 2007 bug. And the listbox cannot be bound in this scenario; it is not setting a field value, it is filtering the form.

Comment: I will test with 2013, but this is not a big issue (but another benefit for subforms ;)

Comment: Now it flickers as bound too. Seems to be sth else, I'll rebuild from scratch and test later.

Comment: On scratch `Ms Access 2013` db both (bound/unbound) flicker too